# Sidebar stops showing on Android Chrome after initial toggle

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-chrome

I'm currently working on a new project and I've been spending the past few days mocking up the HTML, CSS and Java for the layout to work.

I've pretty much finished everything and it looks great on any of the Desktop browers, tablet browsers and all but 1 mobile browser, that being Chrome on Android.

What happens is that i initial move my sidebar off the site with fixed positioning and then -280px (the bars width). Then upon clicking the menu it animates the left positioning to 0 making the bar come on screen aswell as the margin-left of the current content to make it look as if its being pushed over by the side bar.

The first time i click it up on the Android using the Chrome browser everything is perfect, looks spot on but then once i close and open it all the content of the sidebar has disapeared.

Here is the javascript i use to move it (I'm sure it could be done a lot simpler but im no js wizard.)

```
$('#list').click( function() {
    var toggleLeft = $("#left_bar").css('left') == "-280px" ? "0px" : "-280px";
    var toggleWidth = $("#left_bar").css('left') == "-280px" ? "280px" : "0px";
    $('#left_bar').animate({ left: toggleLeft }).toggleClass('active');
    $('#right_bar').animate({ marginLeft: toggleWidth }).toggleClass('noscroll');
    $('#overlay').toggle();
});
```

You can see the entire layout here: [www.dosh.dk/pread/](http://www.dosh.dk/pread/)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. (Rather than adjusting the 'left' property, I was adjusting the 'margin-left' ...I don't remember why.)

My problem was as you described with one exception: It would only occur when in a WebView in a native android app. It worked fine in chrome on android and worked fine in the android default browser.

The work-around was admittedly something to raise an eyebrow at, but we're already dealing with something extremely strange and inexplicable.

I had the bug when the sidebar started at margin-left: 0 in the inactive state, and margin-left: -100% in the active state. **THE FIX**: If I changed the inactive state to margin-left: -1px, it worked as expected. It just needed to peek out ever so slightly in the inactive state, and then it was fine. The part that peeks out is transparent on mine, so no big deal.

Inexplicable bug => inexplicable fix.